# JSON.stringify converts colon inside string to a unicode character

Tags: javascript, json, string, unicode

I have a string object in javascript as given below:

```
time : "YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00.000Z@YYYY-MM-DDT23:59:59.999Z"
```

When I use JSON.stringify to convert the object to string, I get the following string

```
"time=YYYY-MM-DDT00%3A00%3A00.000Z%40YYYY-MM-DDT23%3A59%3A59.999Z"
```

Here 2  characters, i.e., **@** and **:** are being converted to their unicode, which is unwanted behaviour.

How can I prevent this unwanted conversion, so that my string remains unchanged?

Comment: Please show your actual code. `JSON.stringify()` converts a JS object into a JSON encoded string, but the string you have shown is not JSON encoding at all, it looks more like `application/x-www-webform-urlencoded` encoding instead.

Comment: That's not unicode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem, can you show the complete code where the error occurs.
Also, try doing this conversion on the browser console and see what the result comes out to be.

[image: JSON.stringify() works perfectly in my browser console]